# Continuous map from the ring on the unit circle

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Is there a surjective continuous map from the ring $r<x^2+y^2<1\,(0<r<1)$ on the unit circle $x^2+y^2<1$ ?

It seems NO, but how can it be done ?

> **Edit:** what if we add the injectivity to the map ?

Comment: Do you mean onto the unit disc?

Comment: @Michael Albanese: Yes, It is

Comment: there is one tho, try to look for an example, oh and note that the answer changes when you additionaly require the map to be injective

Comment: As for existence of continuous bijective maps: Do you know about homology groups or the fundamental group? If not, you should learn about them and then you can answer questions like this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let me denote $R = \sqrt{r}$, so the ring is defined by $R < |p| < 1$ where $p=(x,y)$. Divide the ring into an inner subring
$$R < |p| \le (R+1)/2
$$
and an outer subring 
$$(R+1)/2 \le |p| < 1
$$
Map the entire inner subring to the origin. Map the outer subring by pulling its inner boundary inward to the origin: for each angle $\theta$, the radial segment of the outer ring of angle $\theta$ connecting the circle of radius $(R+1)/2$ and the circle of radius $1$ is stretched by a constant factor over the radial segment of angle $\theta$ connecting the origin to the circle of radius $1$.

Comment: :OK, thanks. And what if we add the injectivity to the map ? Why does the situation change ?

Answer (score 2):

For $\alpha\in(r,(r+1)/2]~$, the function $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2$ satisfies $f((r,1))=[0,1)$. Then the function $g(x,y)=f(x^2+y^2)$ sends the ring onto the open unit disk.

Answer (score -1):

I find visual building of a map from an open ring to an open circle.

In the three dimension space imagine an open ring as a lateral surface of the cylinder. Now let pull the central line of the cylinder to the point. We have two cones with a common vertex and open boundaries. Finally, project (two-fold covering) these two cones to an open circle (two boundaries of cones map to the boundary of the circle).